# What brand is this screw?

Tags: screws

Does anyone know what brand is this screw? 
I thought it might have good performance on hard wood, and want to buy some but don't know what brand it is.
Here are the pictures of the screw.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you able to predrill the holes?  Screws can't really *drill* because they have no way to physically remove the chips/sawdust.  That is why drills have flutes.  Without removing the material from the hole, you are just compressing the wood fiber in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

If one does not require the center spiral section, I think you'll find a match with a [round washer (truss head) multipurpose torx screw](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N39V3J4):

[image: torx screw]

Answer (score 1):

"[RSS structural screw](https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-google&biw=412&bih=324&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=0TnXWvC1GMnZjwSsuKLgBw&q=+RSS+Structural+Screw&oq=+RSS+Structural+Screw&gs_l=mobile-gws-img.3..0i24.31541.32515..33328...0....100.605.6j1..........1..mobile-gws-wiz-img.qP%2BNz57meX0%3D)" gets us some good results.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a GRK R4™ Multipurpose Star/Torx Screw-#8 Torx Screw.

http://www.rockler.com/grk-r4trade-multipurpose-star-torx-screw-8-torx-screws

Comment: That's a very different head profile.

Comment: @isherwood I'd agree, but that shank spiral is quite distinctive (and perhaps patented) so John may have the right manufacturer.

Comment: Maybe, but the tip isn't right, either.